# Android and slideshow transitions

Tags: android, bitmap, slideshow, transition

I am trying to write a simple slideshow with various transitions between images. 
I would like to have various transitions like fade in, fade out, slide left/right which could probably be done with android's API Animation. But I would also like to have more complex transitions like checkerboard left/right, box in/out, circle in/out, curtain, spiral, split horizontal, and so on which I believe can't be done with Animation.

I know that names of transitions like I named them above are not enough to know exactly how the transitions should look like, but I think you get the general idea.

So, my question is:what should be used to achieve those effects/transitions? I am not asking for the code (though some links to examples would be great of course), but more generally what should I be using? OpenGL? Regions? Clip Paths? BitmapShaders?

I just don't feel like spending a week investigating this, when I am sure you guys know the answer ;)

If possible I would like to avoid OpenGL since I haven't used it. On Android 3.0+ devices I will use hardwareAcceleration="true" in Manifest, and on devices less than 3.0 I could limit to simple slide in/out, fade in/out if necessary (read: if other transitions would be too slow not using openGL).

Comment: Did you figure this one out? What did you end up using?

Comment: share if you found solution !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) and [property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: Thanks, but the way I see it both of these are animating basic properties like rotation, size, scale....with property animation being more powerful. What I need is to animating transition between two Bitmaps, in a way that pixels change in some "unusual" way, for example....here's a link to some transitions to get a better idea: http://javagraphics.blogspot.com/2007/04/slideshows-transitions-swf.html

Comment: @gorann how to use it in android?